# Utility that use the bits service to copy files

Tags: copy, wide-area-network, utility

I would like to know if there is a utility that uses the bits service, to help me transfer some large files over a wacky wan connection. These files happen to be available via a UNC share.

Any suggestions?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

What about [WinBITS](http://www.darvin.de/english/index.html)?

Comment: Not sure if it does what I require- I need to transfer from a UNC.

Comment: It should handle UNC paths. Try it out.

Comment: this utility is not working well..........